# Complicated grouping on multiple properties issue

Tags: c#, .net, linq, duplicates, grouping

I have a large amount of directory type data, with properties like email, telephone, post code etc. I want to detect and group duplicates but on all the multiple properties, where groups can be made up of duplicates on different properties but not all have to be direct duplicates of each other but may be related via another row.

Example data:

```
Name       |     Email     |     Tel     |     Postcode
John Sim   |     j@j.com   |     111     |     C67
J Sim      |               |     111     |
John S     |               |             |     C67
```

I'd like to be able to find a way that I can detect duplicates over the Email, Tel and Postcode properties but even if they don't all match. So in the example above I'd get all 3 of the above grouped, even though the last one has no directed match to the middle one, but the first shares a match with both.

If that makes sense! obviously that is very simplified, I have a 100's of records I'm trying to group in a way I can display the duplicate groups.

So far I have found some very inefficient ways of doing this, involving going through each row, grouping any direct duplicates, but then checking to see if any of those duplicates also have duplicates and if so move them all together into a new group. But I'm trying to find some inspiration and a more efficient way of doing it :)

Thanks!

Comment: What makes those 3 records being duplicates, I only see 2 being eligible ?

Comment: @Aybe It sounds like because first.Tel == second.Tel and first.Postcode == third.Postcode.

Comment: What if last record had a Tel of 999. would that still be considered duplicate?

Comment: Also Do you take into consideration name at all? or completely ignore it?
E.g. if you had a record Jane Doe | Tel: 111, would you want it grouped with this?

Comment: Yeah, requirements are a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the complexity down to O(n) using indexes in a foreach loop and combining on every iteration like the following:

```
        foreach (var entry in list)
        {
            Group emailGroup = null;
            Group telGroup = null;
            Group postcodeGroup = null;

            if (entry.Email != null && _emailGroups.TryGetValue(entry.Email, out emailGroup))
                if (!emailGroup.Add(entry)) emailGroup = null;
            if (entry.Tel != null && _telGroups.TryGetValue(entry.Tel, out telGroup))
                if (!telGroup.Add(entry)) telGroup = null;
            if (entry.Postcode != null && _postcodeGroups.TryGetValue(entry.Postcode, out postcodeGroup))
                if (!postcodeGroup.Add(entry)) postcodeGroup = null;

            if (emailGroup == null && telGroup == null && postcodeGroup == null)
            {
                CreateGroup(entry);
                continue;
            }

            CombineGroups(emailGroup, telGroup, postcodeGroup);
        }
```

Of course, you would have to decide + handle what you want to do on collision etc. and if need be, add any Name logic (e.g. Split First Name + Middle + Last) and then do a 2 way Contains on each (quite expensive so might want to look at string indexes)

Full Code + Test

See Method

```
[Test]
public void Test()
```

in the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentAssertions;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Group> _emailGroups;
        private Dictionary<string, Group> _telGroups;
        private Dictionary<string, Group> _postcodeGroups;

        private void CreateGroup(Entry entry)
        {
            var group = new Group(entry);

            if (group.Email != null && !_emailGroups.ContainsKey(group.Email))
                _emailGroups[group.Email] = group;

            if (group.Tel != null && !_emailGroups.ContainsKey(group.Tel))
                _telGroups[group.Tel] = group;

            if (group.PostCode != null && !_emailGroups.ContainsKey(group.PostCode))
                _postcodeGroups[group.PostCode] = group;
        }

        private void CombineGroups(Group emailGroup, Group telGroup, Group postcodeGroup)
        {
            if (emailGroup != telGroup && emailGroup != null && telGroup != null)
            {
                if (emailGroup.CanCombine(telGroup))
                {
                    emailGroup.Add(telGroup);
                    UpdateIndexes(emailGroup, telGroup);
                    telGroup = null;
                }
                ;
            }

            if (emailGroup != postcodeGroup && emailGroup != null && postcodeGroup != null)
            {
                if (emailGroup.CanCombine(postcodeGroup))
                {
                    emailGroup.Add(postcodeGroup);
                    UpdateIndexes(emailGroup, postcodeGroup);
                    postcodeGroup = null;
                }
                ;
            }

            if (telGroup != postcodeGroup && telGroup != null && postcodeGroup != null)
            {
                if (telGroup.CanCombine(postcodeGroup))
                {
                    telGroup.Add(postcodeGroup);
                    UpdateIndexes(telGroup, postcodeGroup);
                    postcodeGroup = null;
                }
                ;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateIndexes(Group newGroup, Group oldGroup)
        {
            Group group;
            if (oldGroup.Email != null
                && _emailGroups.TryGetValue(oldGroup.Email, out group)
                && group == oldGroup)
                _emailGroups[oldGroup.Email] = newGroup;

            if (oldGroup.Tel != null
                && _telGroups.TryGetValue(oldGroup.Tel, out group)
                && group == oldGroup)
                _telGroups[oldGroup.Tel] = newGroup;

            if (oldGroup.PostCode != null
                && _postcodeGroups.TryGetValue(oldGroup.PostCode, out group)
                && group == oldGroup)
                _postcodeGroups[oldGroup.PostCode] = newGroup;
        }

        public class Group
        {
            public HashSet<Entry> Entries = new HashSet<Entry>();

            public Group(Entry entry)
            {
                Email = entry.Email;
                Tel = entry.Tel;
                PostCode = entry.PostCode;
                Entries.Add(entry);
            }

            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Tel { get; set; }
            public string PostCode { get; set; }

            public bool Matches(Entry entry)
            {
                if (Email != null && entry.Email != null && entry.Email != Email)
                    return false;

                if (Tel != null && entry.Tel != null && entry.Tel != Tel)
                    return false;

                if (PostCode != null && entry.PostCode != null && entry.PostCode != PostCode)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }

            public bool Add(Entry entry)
            {
                if (!Matches(entry))
                    return false;

                Entries.Add(entry);

                if (Email == null && entry.Email != null)
                    Email = entry.Email;

                if (Tel == null && entry.Tel != null)
                    Tel = entry.Tel;

                if (PostCode == null && entry.PostCode != null)
                    PostCode = entry.PostCode;

                return true;
            }

            public bool CanCombine(Group entry)
            {
                if (Email != null && entry.Email != null && Email != entry.Email)
                    return false;

                if (Tel != null && entry.Tel != null && Tel != entry.Tel)
                    return false;

                if (PostCode != null && entry.PostCode != null && PostCode != entry.PostCode)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }

            public void Add(Group group)
            {
                foreach (var entry in group.Entries)
                {
                    Add(entry);
                }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.AppendLine($"Key: {Email ?? "null"} | {Tel ?? "null"} | {PostCode ?? "null"}");

                foreach (var entry in Entries)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(entry.ToString());
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        public class Entry
        {
            public Entry(string name, string email, string tel, string postCode)
            {
                Name = name;
                Email = email;
                Tel = tel;
                PostCode = postCode;
            }

            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Tel { get; set; }
            public string PostCode { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"Entry: {Name ?? "null"} | {Email ?? "null"} | {Tel ?? "null"} | {PostCode ?? "null"}";
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var list = new List<Entry>
            {
                new Entry("John S", null, null, "C67"),
                new Entry("J Sim", null, "111", null),
                new Entry("John Sim", "j@j.com", "111", "C67")
            };

            _emailGroups = new Dictionary<string, Group>();
            _telGroups = new Dictionary<string, Group>();
            _postcodeGroups = new Dictionary<string, Group>();

            foreach (var entry in list)
            {
                Group emailGroup = null;
                Group telGroup = null;
                Group postcodeGroup = null;

                if (entry.Email != null && _emailGroups.TryGetValue(entry.Email, out emailGroup))
                    if (!emailGroup.Add(entry)) emailGroup = null;
                if (entry.Tel != null && _telGroups.TryGetValue(entry.Tel, out telGroup))
                    if (!telGroup.Add(entry)) telGroup = null;
                if (entry.PostCode != null && _postcodeGroups.TryGetValue(entry.PostCode, out postcodeGroup))
                    if (!postcodeGroup.Add(entry)) postcodeGroup = null;

                if (emailGroup == null && telGroup == null && postcodeGroup == null)
                {
                    CreateGroup(entry);
                    continue;
                }

                CombineGroups(emailGroup, telGroup, postcodeGroup);
            }

            var groups = _emailGroups.Select(x => x.Value)
                .Union(_telGroups.Select(x => x.Value))
                .Union(_postcodeGroups.Select(x => x.Value))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

            foreach (var grp in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(grp.ToString());
            }

            groups.Should().HaveCount(1);

            groups.First().Entries.Should().HaveCount(3);
        }
    }
}
```